# Revolution of an area around y axis

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to plot an area that revolves around the y axis in 3D, but can't obtain what I need. I checked alot of related questions but can't really find a solution. I need to make revolve the area between:

> y^2=x and 2y=x

[image: The zone :]
So far , the closest I've got is :

```
RevolutionPlot3D[{y^2, 2 y}, {y, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> All,RevolutionAxis -> Z]
```

[image]
The form seems to be it, but it's not "filled", I have just the surface... So I'm looking to have the whole volume, 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Kuba Yes, and with that I tried
`RegionPlot3D[
 y^4 < x^2 + z^2 < (2 y)^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
 PlotTheme -> "Classic", Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5], 
 BoxRatios -> Automatic, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
 Background -> GrayLevel[0]]`
But didn't work out as expected...

Comment: Can't you just plot both surfaces? `Show[RevolutionPlot3D[Sqrt[x], {x, 0, 4}], RevolutionPlot3D[x/2, {x, 0, 4}]]`

Comment: @Simon Woods Oh yeah,didn't think at that, seems to be perfect, thanks alot !

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in the comments, I plotted both surfaces : 
`Show[RevolutionPlot3D[Sqrt[x], {x, 0, 4}], RevolutionPlot3D[x/2, {x, 0, 4}]]`
Thanks for your help !

Comment: @bbgodfrey I disagree; this is a solution rather than a clarification.  I feel that the question should be closed as "easily found in the documentation" but that is a separate issue.